# distance between a point and a set and open/closed sets

Tags: analysis

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and let $E$ be a subset of $X$ and $x$ be an element of $X$. Define the distance between $x$ and $E$ as $d(x, E) = \inf d(x, y)$, for all $y$ in $E$.

Show that for a fixed set $E$ the function$ f$ given by $f(x)=d(x, E)$ is continuous in the sense that $x_n$ approaches $x$ implies that $f(x_n)$ approaches $f(x)$.

Can any one provide some hints for the above questions, please? Thank you!

Comment: Please put in some details about what you've tried and what you don't understand. That way we can address those issues rather than telling you things you already know.

Comment: Also try to use Tex in the future. See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: So for part (c) I am thinking to construct a sequence of open balls with the following properties: (1) B(x, r) contains the closure of E; (2) The next open ball is contained in its predecessor and so on; (3) The diameter of these open balls will converge to the diameter of the closure of E. How to formulate such a sequence, please?

Comment: You can prove something even stronger: $x \mapsto d(x,E)$ is $1$-Lipschitz!

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that if $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any sequence in $X$, and if $\sigma$ happens to converge to some $x\in X$, then $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to f(x)$. The most straightforward thing to do is to suppose that $\sigma=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a convergent sequence in $X$ and let $x$ be its limit; that much takes essentially no thought.

What does it take to prove that $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle\to f(x)$? We have to show that for each $\epsilon>0$ there is an $m_\epsilon\in\Bbb N$ such that $|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge m_\epsilon$. At this point it seems advisable to see again exactly what $f(x_n)$ and $f(x)$ are:

$$f(x)=\inf_{y\in E}d(x,y)\qquad\text{and}\qquad f(x_n)=\inf_{y\in E}d(x_n,y)\;.$$

We know that we can make $d(x,x_n)$ as small as we like by taking $n$ large enough, since $\sigma$ converges to $x$. We also know that while we may not be able to find a $y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)=f(x)$, we **can** find points $y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)-f(x)$ is as small as we want (short of $0$). In particular, there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $d(x,x_n)<\frac{\epsilon}2$ whenever $n\ge m$, and there is a $y\in E$ such that $d(x,y)-f(x)<\frac{\epsilon}2$, and therefore $d(x,y)<f(x)+\frac{\epsilon}2$. Then for each $n\ge m$ we have

$$d(x_n,y)\le d(x_n,x)+d(x,y)<\frac{\epsilon}2+f(x)+\frac{\epsilon}2=f(x)+\epsilon$$

and hence $f(x_n)\le d(x_n,y)<f(x)+\epsilon$, or $f(x_n)-f(x)<\epsilon$. This is a *very* typical use of the triangle inequality; you’re likely to see quite a few fairly similar arguments.

We’re not done at this point: we want $|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$, not $f(x_n)-f(x)<\epsilon$, so we still need to show that $f(x)-f(x_n)<\epsilon$. This can be done with an argument exactly like the one that I just used, and I’ll leave it to you.